# How insert data in run time in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

i have a table which have 3 column ID, Fname, Lname when i insert data in two column fname and Lname then Id will automatically generated and inserted in ID column that is first 3 char of Fname Column and then underscore and first char of Lname "id may be duplcate"
for cancate i use

```
Select Concat(Left(Fname,3),'_',Left(Lname,1));

Fname        Lname     ID
Ashutosh     Singh     Ash_S
```

Comment: I've never tried this before, but I don't think you should be using functions within functions. Try storing each of those values in variables in php I assume you're using and echoing them to see if you're getting the result you want. If not, modify it and try different apporaches.

Comment: So what is the question??

Comment: if you want to insert in table then use insert statement and set id as auto_increment and primary key

Comment: my question is this when i insert data in Fname and Lname column at the same id is generated on the behalf of Fname and Lname and Id is inserted in ID column id may be duplicate

Answer (score 1):

USE integer as PK.

```
create table users(
  id serial,
  my_key varchar(5),
  fname varchar(50),
  lname varchar(50)
);
```

first 3 char of Fname Column and then underscore and first char of Lname
could not be unique

my_key can be filled by on "insert" trigger - .

Comment: I second this. Use a true unique integer key as primary key. You don't want to use a key that depends on other columns. You would have to resolve conflicts... and recalc it when first and last names change... or have it misaligned. And remember that to keep this user key aligned you must handle both the before insert and the before update trigger ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make a trigger on insert action so that it fills the ID column using the business logic you mentioned